# Livecode can't test iPhone app: 'unable to find ibtool'

Tags: ios, livecode

`Mac OS Big Sur 11.5`  /  `Livecode Community Edition 9.6.3-rc-2  / Xcode 12.5.1`

I'm trying to test a small app for `iPhone` in the `Livecode` development app.
This very same app worked on my `iPhone` a few years ago. Now I open it in `Livecode` and use the Test button; it begins compiling then says:

```
"Unable to build app for simulation: failed to create launch screen: scrub: error: unable to find utility "ibtool", not a developper tool or in PATH"
```

That message makes no sense to me. I checked here and the `Livecode` site but could find no useful info. ibtool seems to be a nasty, recurring, problem.

What is the matter? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Xcode Preferences under "Locations" that the version of the command line tools is the same as the version of Xcode you have selected in LiveCode Preferences under "Mobile Support".
These kind of issues often are caused by the wrong version of these command line tools that LiveCode uses to build the app.